# Python splitting text file keeping newlines

Tags: python, split, newline, counter

I am trying to split up a text file into words, with `\n` being counted as a word.

My input is this text file:

```
War and Peace

by Leo Tolstoy/Tolstoi
```

And I want a list output like this:

```
['War','and','Peace','\n','\n','by','Leo','Tolstoy/Tolstoi']
```

Using `.split()` I get this:

```
['War', 'and', 'Peace\n\nby', 'Leo', 'Tolstoy/Tolstoi']
```

So I started writing a program to put the \n as a separate entry after the word, code following:

```
for oldword in text:
counter = 0
newword = oldword
while "\n" in newword:
    newword = newword.replace("\n","",1)
    counter += 1

text[text.index(oldword)] = newword

while counter > 0:
    text.insert(text.index(newword)+1, "\n")
    counter -= 1
```

However, the program seems to hang on the line `counter -= 1`, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

NOTE: I realise that were this to work, the result would be ['Peaceby',"\n","\n"]; that is a different problem to be solved later.

Comment: Your formatting is off. Not sure waht the fix is. line 2 and 3 should probably indented below `for oldword in text:` ?

Comment: I doubt you get `'Peace\n\nby'`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you would if you did `split(' ')`. Perhaps that's what OP meant.

Comment: Everything was indented under the for loop, got lost in copy/paste. I did use split(" ") to avoid losing the newlines.

Comment: If you replace "\n" with " \n " (spaces added), then a split(" ") should get you close to what you want.  It may contain empty elements that you will have to eliminiate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need such complicated way, You can simply use regex and `re.findall()` to find all the words and new lines:

```
>>> s="""War and Peace
... 
... by Leo Tolstoy/Tolstoi"""
>>> 
>>> re.findall(r'\S+|\n',s)
['War', 'and', 'Peace', '\n', '\n', 'by', 'Leo', 'Tolstoy/Tolstoi']
```

`'\S+|\n'` will match all the combinations of none whitespace character with length 1 or more (`\S+`) or new line (`\n`).

If you want to get the text from a file you can do the following:

```
with open('file_name') as f:
     re.findall(r'\S+|\n',f.read())
```

Read more about regular expressions http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Looks great, but I didn't understand a word you just said, or how this fits in to the code.

Comment: Ok, thanks, got it to work. However, I lose all punctuation such as apostrophes and the '/' between Tolstoy and Tolstoi.

Comment: @ChristopherRiches Sorry I updated the regex, check the edit.

Comment: @msw I don't think so, maybe there was another ways but I think this is very straight approach and as you know *Beautiful is better than ugly*.
*Explicit is better than implicit*.
*Simple is better than complex*.
*Complex is better than complicated*.

Comment: @Kasramvd Thanks, it now works. I do not have time to trawl through the regex site, so could you please explain to me exactly what (r'\S+|\n') means?

Comment: @ChristopherRiches Welcome, I explained it in answer, however `\S` will match a single none whitespace character like alphabetical characters or punctuations and modifier `+` will makes the regex engine to match its preceding token 1 or more time and `|` is a logical OR which means the sub string would be `\S+` or `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of both `\n` characters and split by spaces successfully to get each index of the list being a different word, you can first replace the values of `\n\n` with a single space...`string.replace('\n\n', ' ')` and equate it to a new string, then split by spaces...`newString.split(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

As you are reading a file you can handle things line by line which allows you split a line at a time handling the newlines appropriately:

```
>>> [word for line in inputFile for word in line.rstrip('\n').split() + ['\n']]
['War', 'and', 'Peace', '\n', '\n', 'by', 'Leo', 'Tolstoy/Tolstoi', '\n']
```

The simple breakdown:

- `for line in inputFile`: For each line in the inputFile
- `for word in line.rstrip('\n').split() + ['\n']`: Strip off the newline and split the line adding the new line back on as a separate element

As noted if you use `split()` with no separator then you don't actually need the `rstrip('\n')`.

You could use these exact expressions as a loop instead of a list comprehension:

```
result = []
for line in inputFile:
    for word in line.rstrip('\n').split():
        result.append(word)
    result.append('\n')
print(result)
```

Which gives the sames output:

```
['War', 'and', 'Peace', '\n', '\n', 'by', 'Leo', 'Tolstoy/Tolstoi', '\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

This yet another variation:

```
with open('data.txt') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        words.extend(line.split())
        words.append('\n')
```

It splits for words at all spaces including tabs.